# How to reduce the default margin/padding applied by ant design between elements in <Form>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

[image]
I am using ant design `<Form layout="vertical">` and I want to set the space between Price Map elements inside `<Form>` to be less. I tried setting `style={{margin:"0px"}}` on elements but it has no change on UI.

Here's the code for the Price Map.

```
            <Form.Item
              label="Price Map"
              rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input Prices!" }]}
            >
              {selectedProducts.flatMap(productId =>
                products
                  .filter(product => product.id === productId)
                  .map(product => (
                    <Input.Group compact layout="horizontal">
                      <Form.Item label={product.productName + " : "} />
                      {product.priceList.map(priceObj => (
                        <Input
                              defaultValue={priceObj.price}
                              addonBefore={priceObj.type}
                              rules={[
                                  {
                                      required: true,
                                      message: "Please input price!"
                                  }
                              ]}
                              
                              style={{ width: "34%" }}
                        />
                      ))}
                    </Input.Group>
                  ))
              )}
            </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Form.Item style={{ marginBottom: 0 }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]I was able to achieve this by setting `style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}` for the `<Input>`

 
Here's my updated code.

```
            <Form.Item
              label="Price Map"
              rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input Prices!" }]}
            >
              {selectedProducts.flatMap(productId =>
                products
                  .filter(product => product.id === productId)
                  .map(product => (
                    <Input.Group compact layout="horizontal">
                          <div style={{ marginRight: 5 }}> { product.productName + " : " }</div>
                      {product.priceList.map(priceObj => (
                        <Input
                              defaultValue={priceObj.price}
                              addonBefore={priceObj.type}
                              rules={[
                                  {
                                      required: true,
                                      message: "Please input price!"
                                  }
                              ]}
                              onChange={(changedValue) => {
                                  setPriceMap({
                                      ...priceMap,
                                      [priceObj.priceId]: priceObj.price
                                  });
                              }}
                              style={{ width: "34%" , marginBottom: 5 }}
                        />
                      ))}
                    </Input.Group>
                  ))
              )}
            </Form.Item>
```